# IFrame: This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, iframe

I have two internal sites.  I'm trying to show one's content in the iframe of the other site.  However I'm getting this message: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame."  I've read the reason I'm getting this message but, I would like to bypass it since the sites are internal and I'm not concerned with someone trying to hijack my users.  I couldn't find a way to bypass it after searching the internet, but feel like it should be possible because the rest of the message seems to hint at it.

**"To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."**

Since I'm the publisher how can I allow it to be displayed in the frame? Thanks!

Comment: Are these sites part of some other system (i.e. CMS of some kind), and if so it is possible that it is a configuration of that system?  Otherwise, are the internal sites hosted on different domains, and if so does the iframe site have the `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` header?

Comment: @freefaller, thanks for the reply! Where would I set the `X-Frame-Options` at?

Comment: It's a header value, not part of the HTML, so you need to be looking in `Response.AddHeader`.  The value is designed to stop a site being used within an iframe... Google (for example) does this to stop you creating a full-size iframe and pretending they are actually your site. To be honest, my guess is it's nothing to do with it, but have a look at [this for more information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2694329)

Comment: see in html source to find:<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">

Comment: For those that get this issue with SharePoint 2013: [IFraming SharePoint-hosted pages in apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps.aspx) ... I haven't tested the solution of adding the "AllowingFraming" component to the Master Page yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">` in the one to show in the iframe  to allow it.

Comment: Do you add this tag to the page containing the content, or to the page containing the frame?

Comment: @AdamDenoon The page containing the content.

Comment: didn't work for me, I'm trying to show google.com in the iframe

Comment: @AbeerSul You can only do that if *you* have control over the web page being shown in the iframe, which I'm guessing is not the case for google.

Comment: per MDN: Note: Setting the meta tag is useless! For instance, <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> has no effect. Do not use it! Only by setting through the HTTP header like the examples below, X-Frame-Options will work.

Answer (score 9):

The X-Frame-Options is defined in the Http Header and not in the `<head>` section of the page you want to use in the iframe.

Accepted values are: DENY, SAMEORIGIN and  ALLOW-FROM "url"

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_top"` attribute in anchor tag that will really work.