# How can I use jquery to open a modal window that is NOT an overlay

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have standard links on a page that I can easily get to open in a new window with the target attribute... or using onclick to kick off a function.  What I'd like to do is, instead of using the target attribute, use jquery to open a modal window with definable width/height, and maybe place an opaque overlay on the calling window while waiting for the modal to close.

Every search I'm doing has results for either loading content through ajax or some hidden page content (div).  This is a cross-domain link, so it must be a new window.  I'm thinking there should be some simple jquery function I can hook into the class that will read the href value and perform the open.

Comment: iframe would be fine, but does not work with cross-domain links... even in a redirect situation, I've tried.

Comment: I actually not quite understand what you trying to achieve overall and why does iframe doesn't work for cross-domain links. Any fiddle that we can have a look?

Comment: "This content cannot be displayed in a frame - To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame ?

Comment: I already discovered that, cherhan.  x-frame-options is not a consideration, I don't have control over the redirected-to page headers.