# How to allow IFRAME in VS Team Service custom TAB

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, azure-devops, visual-studio-extensions

I have an extension that adds custom TAB in VSTS see image below

[image]

It  works perfectly fine in chrome but not in IE see image below for the result:

[image]

This the code inside my extension:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    VSS.init();
    VSS.ready(function () {
        var webContext = VSS.getWebContext();
        var projectName = webContext.project.name;
        var assetFrame = document.getElementById("assetFrame");

        assetFrame.src = "https://samplewebsite.net/Home/Asset/" + projectName;
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();

    });
</script>
<div id="rtlTabBody">
    <iframe id="assetFrame" style="width:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Do I need to configure something in the code or in VSTS itself to allow iframe?

Comment: Is the content page site managed by you?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT You mean `https://samplewebsite.net/` ? yes

Comment: Then try updating that site to allow it to be displayed in other frame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I tried to embed iframe to another web app not VSTS and it works perfectly fine, do you think VSTS is preventing us to embed IFRAME?

Comment: No, VSTS allow this. "If you have a web page that can be hosted in a an iframe, it can be hosted in Visual Studio Team Services as a hub." This is the description from VSTS document: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content security policy (CSP) of the site you are trying to embed has configured itself to disallow it to be embedded in a different website.

It's either specifying:

```
frame-ancestors 'none'
```

Or it's older equivalent:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I suspect the latter, as X-Frame-Options is deprecated in favor of CSP [and Chrome only partially implements it](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/tools/xframeoptions/).