# Display site A in an iFrame on site B only works for Chrome (X-Frame-Option)

Tags: iframe, cross-browser, x-frame-options

I want to load a page from site A and display it in an iFrame on another site B (different domains).
To achieve this I added following header on site A:

```
X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://view.targeturl.com/
X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM https://www.targeturl.com/
```

Loading the iFrame on site B works fine in Chrome but not in FF nor IE

In FF the iFrame stays empty and the console says:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.targeturl.com/ does not
>   permit framing by https://view.targeturl.com/content/id/1241 (unknown)

In IE the iFrame says:

> this content cannot be displayed in a frame

Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow"/>` to the `<head></head>` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14221928/2635490)) doesn't help either.

Sine I've control about the servers this must be fixable - or not?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, Please share if you get any solution