# How to see the content of iframe in html

Tags: html, iframe

I'm trying to view google.com on iframe but it gives me an error in Internet Explorer 11(Default) and Document Mode 7(Default);

[IFrame: This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame) this answer doesn't work for me

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame 

To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

And there is a blank page on Google Chrome.My code is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the error it says that Google doesn't allow people to use their website into a frame.
So you could not do that

Comment: I think it's not about google because I try to view some other pages and it also gives the same error and I try to view my xbap so it's same.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="allow">` would need to be on the page that you wish to show _within the iframe_. Since this page is controlled by Google, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: @Turnip firstly there are similar questions and no of them fix my problem and I said that.Why you marked my question as duplicate secondly I said that it's not about google chrome it is still cannot show my xbap too

Comment: It has nothing to do with Google Chrome. The security settings of the page that you are trying to display prevent it from being loaded in an iframe. If you do not control the page, you can not fix the problem. If you do control the page, then add the correct `X-Frame-Options` headers. If you don't think your question is a duplicate then you need to explain why within your question.  As it stands, your question is a duplicate.

Comment: You have to make fully trust in your xbap.