# iFrame not displaying PDF page

Tags: html, django, pdf, iframe

I am trying to load a PDF into an iFrame. `src` is set to the URL received from a database.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <iframe runat="server" src="{{quotation.quotationFile.url}}" 
          width="100%" height="500px">  </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to load an iFrame with `src` received from database. But it's not displaying:

```
This content can’t be shown in a frame
There is supposed to be some content here, but the publisher doesn’t allow it to be displayed in a frame. This is to help protect the security of any information you might enter into this site.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IFrame: This content cannot be displayed in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141388/iframe-this-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame)

Comment: I guess you are not the owner of the page which contains the PDF. And this page is forbidding embedding their content on other websites.

Answer (score 0):

maybe frame it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
in Django have 3 X-Frame-Options

1. DENY
2. SAMEORIGIN
3. ALLOW-RROM

can refer to this:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/#an-example-of-clickjacking

Comment: can you please explain ,how i have to set X-Frame-Options